# Create kafka topic using predefined config files

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

Is there any way to create kafka topic in kafka/zookeeper configuration files *before* I will run the services, so once they will start - the topics will be in place?

I have looked inside of script `bin/kafka-topics.sh` and found that in the end, it executes a live command on the live server. But since the server is here, its config files are here and zookeeper with its configs also are here, is it a way to predefined topics in advance?
Unfortunately haven't found any existing config keys for this.

Answer (score 0):

The servers need to be running in order to allocate metadata and log directories for them, so no